# OpenGL strange color

Tags: opengl, textures, forward-compatibility

We are upgrading our game from OpenGL 2.1 to 3.1 core (forward compatible) context.
It all works very well except one minor but very strange glitch.

We have a white fill texture that somehow becomes red after the 3D world loads.
I.e. it starts giving vec3(1,0,0) in fragment shaders when sampling instead of vec3(1,1,1).

It only happens on 3.1 forward compatible contexts. Compatibility 3.1 and even core 3.1 contexts don't exhibit this. There are no GL errors. And, it happens on both Intel and nVidia GPUs.

What could it be?

Comment: It "could be" a lot of things; without your code, we can't say. Also, why OpenGL 3.1 instead of 3.3 or 4.5? It seems a pretty odd place to stop, since any 3.1 capable hardware can also handle 3.3.

Comment: What `internalFormat` are you using for that texture?

Comment: 3.1 core profile does not exist. Profiles were introduced with GL 3.2, so what you say doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Source code at https://svn.thedarkmod.com/svn/darkmod_src/trunk. 3.1 because many Intel graphics were left with drivers that only do that. 3.1 core is a real thing.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Why post a link that is password protected?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link copy pasted from wiki. https://svn.thedarkmod.com/publicsvn/darkmod_src/trunk/

Comment: @derhass I see what you mean. Right, there's no core/compatibility contexts in 3.1. So the difference here is 'regular' 3.1 vs future compatible 3.1 contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that by mistake I was corrupting our white texture by using it to capture depth buffer. As a result, it had internal format of DEPTH_COMPONENT which is LUMINANCE vs RED depending on forward compatibility.
[image]